# Expandable List View Using String Array in XML File

Tags: android, xml, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have two continents Asia and Europe. The List of countries in Asia and Europe are stored as a String Array in Resource File, withing respective files. I want to use Asia and Europe as groups and the countries as their child entities. How can we access string arrays stored in resource file and use it in ExpandableListAdapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, ur problem was quite a challenging one, and I like challenges. Hence i sat down to code and developed a solution for ur problem. I am pasting the code down here. Hope it will be helpful for u........

```
 public class ExpandableList1 extends ExpandableListActivity {

    ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set up our adapter
        mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Sample menu");
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, R.string.expandable_list_sample_action);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        String title = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();

        int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
        if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
            int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
            int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition); 
            Toast.makeText(this, title + ": Child " + childPos + " clicked in group " + groupPos,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        } else if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
            int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
            Toast.makeText(this, title + ": Group " + groupPos + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        // Sample data set.  children[i] contains the children (String[]) for groups[i].
        private String[] groups = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);
        private String[][] children =  {getResources().getStringArray(R.array.asianCountries),
               getResources().getStringArray(R.array.africanCountries),getResources().getStringArray(R.array.europeanCountries)};





        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
        }

        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return children[groupPosition].length;
        }

        public TextView getGenericView() {
            // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
            AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 64);

            TextView textView = new TextView(ExpandableList1.this);
            textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            // Center the text vertically
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
            // Set the text starting position
            textView.setPadding(55, 0, 0, 0);
            return textView;
        }

        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = getGenericView();
            textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
            return textView;
        }

        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groups[groupPosition];
        }

        public int getGroupCount() {
            return groups.length;
        }

        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = getGenericView();
            textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
            return textView;
        }

        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: getChildView and getGroupView should check whether convertView is null, and only create a new view if it is; otherwise reuse the existing convertView.

Comment: Also, rather than creating a new view in code, you can just inflate a layout, particularly one of the default ones:    if (convertView == null) {
  convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, null);
}